# failing to display a custom font

Tags: customization

I think this is a pretty common issue. I just spent an hour trying to figure out what's wrong... my custom wordpress theme doesn't display a custom font.
Here's the code:

```
@font-face {
font-family: Proxima;
src: url(fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.otf);  
}
```

It's strange, because I have another instance of the exact same WP site on a different host and that works just fine.. wordpress is driving me crazy sometimes.

Any ideas on how to solve this?
Thanks

Comment: Sometimes these font issues are browser-specific, as some browsers favor one file type that others do not (and likewise with those).  Furthermore, your `url` is a relative one (with respect to the .css file from which it's invoked), and you might ensure that you're pointing at the appropriate location.

Comment: @JustinBell I already tried different combinations of both relative and absolute (exact path within the wordpress hierarchy on the server). I can show you example... this is the working site: http://tasmaniandevilz.com/mima
And this is the one that I am dealing with: http://misiamariina.sk. The CSS code is exactly the same. What would you advice me to do? I can't use Google fonts, since the font is not supported. Is there any other way of defining custom fonts?

Comment: I am fairly certain that this is not WordPress

Comment: well you are wrong then I guess.. anyway, this is a solved issue, no point in further comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mike94,

Upon looking at [your site](http://misiamariina.sk/) I noticed this while viewing the style.css file (*wp-content/themes/mima/style.css?ver=325*):

```
@font-face {
font-family: Proxima;
src: url(../fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.otf);
}
```

Thus, what is being asked for is wp-content/themes/mima/../fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.otf (which does not exist); however, I did find the font file by removing the `../` from the `src`.

However, on viewing your site, I also encountered another issue:

```
Redirect at origin 'http://www.misiamariina.sk' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://misiamariina.sk' is therefore not allowed access. misiamariina.sk/:1
```

This message showed in Chrome.  It appears that `http://www.misiamariina.sk` is redirected to `http://misiamariina.sk`, but all of your resources advertise themselves at the `www.` address.  Your http server has apparently denied access to at least one file (which I believe to be the font file in question), and so your CORS policy restricts you from automatically downloading this resource.  How you address this depends on your environment:

- [IIS](http://evolpin.wordpress.com/2012/10/12/the-cors/)
- [Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20838470)
- [Nginx](https://serverfault.com/questions/384105/cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-with-nginx-chrome)

Comment: oh, great. That solved the problem. First I put the redirect back on www.misiamariina.sk and checked the font. Then I changed both the wordpress address and the site address to misiamariina.sk. I had to restore my password, because I wasn't able to log in, but now everything works :) I would never imagine that the redirect was causing problems. Thanks.